# checking an input is a single letter in python

Tags: python, string, loops

im trying to check that the input the user enters is either a single letter or word and not an integer or nothing, if they enter something which isnt valid then they should be kept in the loop until they enter a single letter.
this is my code so far but it doesnt seem to be working in the desired way:

```
animalcount = 0
animal = 0
data = False
while data == False:
    try:
        letter = str(input("what letter would you like to search for? "))
        data = True
    except:
        print ("please enter a letter, try again.")
    if letter == "":
        print ("please enter an item,try again!")
        data = False
for animal in animallist:
    if letter in animal:
        print(animal)
        animalcount = animalcount + 1
if animalcount == 0:
    print ("That letter cannot be found")
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?  Are you on python2.x or python3.x?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Answer (score 1):

Making a string from input will not achieve much since anything you enter with the keyboard will work perfectly fine as a string.

You could use a regexp to distinguish between letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple loop at the top.

```
import string
letter = None
while not letter or letter not in string.letters:
    letter = str(raw_input("What letter would you like to search for? "))
```

Then the rest should work.